# Can Entity Framework handle like with underscore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In T-SQL, I can do this:

```
declare @a varchar(500) = 'aaip'

select 1 where @a like '_ip'
```

In Entity Framework, it seems I can only use contain, which will be translated to percent sign (%). Is there a way to create like statement with underscore? There is a 2017 stackoverflow question on this and the answer is a NO, just wondering if there are some better ways now.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: we are using framework 4.8 microsoft.entityframeworkcore.

Comment: And which version of EF Core?

Comment: version is 3.1.16

Comment: Use [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Core's SQL Server provider [has mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#string-functions) for [`DbFunctionsExtensions.Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-3.1) method. Something like `.Where(e => EF.Functions.Like(e.SomeColumn, "_p"))` should do the trick.